# Finding the "top" boss in a hierarchy of bosses works only on some test cases

Tags: c++, dictionary

UPDATE:

I have fixed the code such that every test case I can come up with has given me the correct result, but I'm still missing something because the online judge is still saying it's wrong.  I've included the code immediately following this paragraph.  I know the approach I've taken is ugly and not very efficient, but I don't care.  I just want this to output the correct answer now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
map<string, string> names;
map<string, int > bossCount;

vector<string> bosses;
string topBoss;
int n;
int max = 0;

cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    bool add = true;
    string c1, c2;
    cin >> c1 >> c2;
    names[c1] = c2;
    for (int i = 0; i < bosses.size(); i++)
    {
        if (bosses[i] == c2)
            add = false;
        //bosses.push_back(c2);
    }
    if (add == true)
        bosses.push_back(c2);
}

for (map<string, string>::iterator it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++)
    for(int i = 0; i < bosses.size(); i++)
    {
        if (bosses[i] == (*it).second)
        {
            bossCount[bosses[i]]++;
        }
    }

for (map<string, string>::iterator it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++)
    for (int i = 0; i < bosses.size(); i++)
    {
        if (bosses[i] == (*it).first)
        {
            bossCount[bosses[i]] = 0;
            bossCount[(*it).second]++;
        }
    }

for (map<string, int>::iterator it = bossCount.begin(); it != bossCount.end(); it++)
{
    if((*it).second == max)
    {
        if ((*it).first < topBoss)
            topBoss = (*it).first;
    }

    if ((*it).second > max)
    {
        max = (*it).second;
        topBoss = (*it).first;
    }       
}   

cout << topBoss;

return 0;
}
```

I am given a list of unique names and their boss that they report to (the bosses are not unique). I must then find which boss has the highest hierarchy. This means, several of the first unique names in the list could have the same boss, but then that boss could have his own boss, which means the first unique names answer to their boss's boss, and so the boss's boss wins the hierarchy.  Here's the problem in its entirety:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkz8E.png

I have written the code, and it works in the sample test case provided in the problem (outputs Napoleon).  It has also worked in a few other test cases I've thrown at it, but then it doesn't work when I use this test case, for example:

```
4
a b
c b
d b
b e
```

I believe the correct answer should be "e" since "b"'s boss is "e".  My program outputs b in this test case.  Can someone help spot the issue here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
map<string, string> names;
map<string, int > bossCount;

queue<string> next;
vector<string> bosses;
string topBoss;
    int n;
int max = 0;

cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string c1, c2;
    cin >> c1 >> c2;
    names[c1] = c2;
    bosses.push_back(c2);
}

for (map<string, string>::iterator it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++)
    for(int i = 0; i < bosses.size(); i++)
    {
        if (bosses[i] != (*it).first)
        {
            bossCount[bosses[i]]++;
        }
    }

for (map<string, int>::iterator it = bossCount.begin(); it != bossCount.end(); it++)
{
    if((*it).second == max)
    {
        if ((*it).first < topBoss)
            topBoss = (*it).first;
    }

    else if ((*it).second > max)
    {
        max = (*it).second;
        topBoss = (*it).first;
    }


}

cout << topBoss;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: getting a 404 on the link.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Strange.  It's working for me.  Here's the indirect link:  http://imgur.com/nyTgW

Comment: This is a topological sort and is usually solved using recursion.

Comment: @brianbeuning Yes, thank you.  But my code almost works, and I'm hoping to find a fix within what I've already written.  I'm guessing I've forgotten to check for something, but I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: You compute bossCount[] but don't use it. hint - the boss with 0 bosses would be special.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to build a set of trees for the hierarchy and then do a depth-last traversal.

The only candidates for top boss are ones with no boss. So the data structure should easily record this. (If the hierarchy always has one top boss, then you can solve the problem simply by returning the unique individual with no boss of his own.)

So I suggest a `std::multimap` from the boss to the underlings. Putting a null/empty name into the map returns the top bosses.

Keep a stack or use functional recursion to navigate from the top to the bottom of the org chart, then add up the size of the hierarchy on the return trip from the bottom to the top.

Comment: I'm not looking to rewrite this, or complete the task in the most efficient, cleanest manner.  I have an online, automatic judge that tests the output, and I want to know if there's a way I can adjust my current code to make it work.  If there isn't a way, and I have to rewrite it, then I'm going to take the loss on this one.

Comment: @TheRationalist If a rewrite is just a few lines long, then that's the way to go. And getting a simple solution is really the point of a problem like this. The notion of progressing closer and closer to a solution until it's done simply doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The computation of the boss count,

```
for (map<string, string>::iterator it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++)
    for(int i = 0; i < bosses.size(); i++)
    {
        if (bosses[i] != (*it).first)
        {
            bossCount[bosses[i]]++;
        }
    }
```

seems wrong to me.

It looks like "for each underling U: increase the boss count of all bosses who are not U".

Anyway, an easy way to go about the boss count is to use a `std::multiset`. Every time a name appears as underling, add it to the multiset. The final count of each name in the multiset is then the number of bosses this person has, and only the top boss has 0 bosses.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep your code as similar as possible you can change this:

```
    if (bosses[i] != (*it).first)
    {
        bossCount[bosses[i]]++;
    }
```

to this

```
    if (bosses[i] == (*it).second)
    {
        bossCount[bosses[i]]++;
    }
```

But this still hasn't solved you problem as you do not take into account the hierarchy where names belong to their boss's boss.

Comment: Thanks to your pointing this out, I have updated my code such that every example I have thrown at it is giving me the correct answer, however, I'm still getting the solution wrong according to the online judge.  I posted the new code in my post if interested.